# Static methods & variables in instantiated classes

Tags: java, static

Say I have a class `Person`, which has a method `doSomething()`. I create a `static ArrayList<Person> people`, and a method `doSomethingToAllPeople()` which calls `doSomething()` for each `Person` in `people`. Should I put `people` and `doSomethingToAllPeople()` in the `Person` class or in a different `PersonManager` class? Does it even matter? Here is some example code:

```
class Person
{
    public void doSomething()
    {
        //stuff here
    }
}

//where should the following code go?
static List<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    people.add(new Person());
}
static void doSomethingToAllPeople()
{
    for(Person person : people)
    {
        person.doSomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `static` placeholders as little as possible. I'd recommend you create a `PersonRepository` class with an instance member `List<Person>`. Create an instance of `PersonRepository` and have it manage your `Person`s

Comment: You'd acheive the same functionallity. It's basically a matter of taste, and a matter of if you want anyone using `Person` to be exposed to `people`.

Comment: I agree with @Sotirios, but if it's just one place where you need to manage something for a bunch of `people` (e.g. `List<Person>`), I'd just pass the `List<Person>` as an argument to the static method `doSomethingToAllPeople()`.

Comment: Just think of static as something that will last for entire application lifetime. variable or class is usually declared static if you want only one instance during entire lifetime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, it doesn't matter and is a matter of preference. However, if you want my opinion, I would consider keeping your `Person` class independent of your collection of `Person`s. Keeping these two parts separate preserves flexibility of the class, and one of the great things about Java is that it enables you to create nice, contained, reusable classes.
 Consider a `PersonRegistry` class that implements a **factory design pattern**. It might have a method that creates an instance of `Person` and adds this instance to a collection before returning. This will enable to achieve your desired functionality while keeping `Person` independent and flexible.